# How to format a Label to have a Display Format String?

Tags: wpf, formatting, label, mask

I have a Label:

```
<Label Name="lblBilledDate"
       Content="{Binding Path=BilledDate, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Label>
```

It is bound to a `DateTime` value.

How can i change the label to display the value to this: `DisplayFormatString="dd MMM yyyy"`

Currently the Label just dispalys: 1/1/2010

I need it to dispaly: 1 Jan 2010

Comment: I think the answer would involve adding some attributes to your binding expression, so this would be easier to answer if you hadn't removed the binding from the XAML you posted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`ContentStringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat) attribute.

```
<Label x:Name="SomeLabel"
       Content="{Binding BilledDate}"
       ContentStringFormat="dd MMM yyyy" />
```

This is because `Label` inherits from `ContentControl`. Any `ContentControl` contains the `ContentStringFormat` attribute. Additionally, `ItemsControl` has `ItemStringFormat` and `BindingBase` has `StringFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```
<Label name="lblSomeLabel">
    <Binding Path="Date" StringFormat="{}{0:dd MMM yyyyy}"/>
</Label>
```